# Ubuntu 16.04 firefox 48 Old bug solved returns over and over again

Tags: upgrade

1. First bug I started with: ̈́Firefox is already running, but is not responding.' Solved with: 
   ps aux
   kill PId
2. When I restart I have to use safe mode, then I lose all security and the scams , ads, viruses, etc enter.
3. Then, very nicely, Firefox sends me this message:
   'Well, this is embarrassing.
   Firefox is having trouble recovering your windows and tabs. This is usually caused by a recently opened web page.

You can try:

```
Removing one or more tabs that you think may be causing the problem
Starting an entirely new browsing session'
```

4. Then, I go to Firefox HELP and click on 'Restart with Adds-on Enabled
5. The problem start all over again:  ̈́Firefox is already running, but is not responding.'

Thank you,
Beatriz

Comment: The title is not descriptive of the problem.  BTW, you can kill processes more easily using `killall` and `pkill`.

Answer (score 1):

One ore more of your Firefox add-ons or plug-ins are causing problems. You can isolate the add-on or plug-in:

1. Terminate all running Firefox instances. Use `killall firefox` if necessary.
2. Start Firefox in safe mode (`firefox -safe-mode`).
3. Disable all add-ons and plug-ins. Restart Firefox in normal mode.
4. Re-enable a few add-ons/plug-ins and restart Firefox.
5. If Firefox runs without issues, go back to step 4.

   If the just enabled add-ons/plug-ins seem to cause problems:
6. Start Firefox in safe mode (see steps 1–2).
7. Disable all but one of the add-ons/plug-ins enabled in step 4. Go back to step 5 and repeat until you can narrow down the issues to a single (or more rarely multiple) add-on or plug-in.

Once you isolated the problematic add-on/plug-in, please [open a new question](/questions/ask) to ask how to deal with that.

Comment: As you’re a reputation 4 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!